# Cakephp Find Recursive Associations

Tags: cakephp

My Cakephp Application Has the following models with relations ships

```
class Category extends AppModel {
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
'Product' => array(
'className' => 'Product',
'joinTable' => 'products_categories',
'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'product_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
    ),
);
}

class Product extends AppModel {
public $primaryKey = 'id';
public $hasMany = array(
    'ProductSwatch' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductSwatch',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
         'dependent' => true
    ),
    'ProductDimension' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductDimension',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
         'dependent' => true
    ),
    'ProductCare' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductCare',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
         'dependent' => true
    ),
    'ProductDimension' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductDimension',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    ),
    'ProductCare' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductCare',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'dependent' => false,
    ),
    'Review' => array(
        'className' => 'Review',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
         'dependent' => true,
    )
);
}
```

When i am finding all the Category elements only Product Model contents are coming is there any way to get the Products associations(ProductDimension, ProductSwatches, etc) when we fetch the Categories model?

Comment: use ContainableBehavior http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Comment: Please always include a tag for what version of CakePHP you're using.

Answer (score 0):

By default CakePHP 2 recursion level is 1st level association only.
You can use `recursive` option of `find` (or model property) to fetch deep associations.

For more information about model `recursive` property, see: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive

For example:

```
$this->Category->find('all', array(
    'recursive' => 2,
    'conditions' => array(), // Your conditions, etc.
));
```

Another **(and better way)** is using `Containable` behaviour.

add

> public $actsAs = array('Containable');

to your model(s) to enable `Containable` behaviour. Then you can use:

```
$this->Category->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Product' => array(
            'ProductSwatch',
            'ProductDimension',
            'ProductCare',
            'Review',
        ),
    ),
    'conditions' => array(), // Your conditions, etc.
));
```

to fetch deeper associations.

For more information about `Containable` behaviour and deeper associations, see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations